# Calling private function from another private function in same class in PHP

Tags: php

I have a private function, that calculate number of working saturdays. Then i have a seperate small private function that retrieve holidays for certain date intervals from database. So im calling this holiday function from another fucntion. But it is not working.

```
class DashboardPage{

    private function getWorkingDays($FirstDate,$LastDate,$holidays){    
        $endDate =  strtotime($LastDate);
        $startDate = strtotime($FirstDate);    
        //Calculate even saturdays  
        $end = date("Y-m-d h:m:s",strtotime("+1 day",strtotime($LastDate)));  //Add one day to include LastDate 
        $all_days = new DatePeriod(new DateTime($FirstDate), new DateInterval('P1D'), new DateTime($end));  
        foreach ($all_days as $day) {               

                $dayOfWeek = (int)$day->format('w'); //0-6, 6 = Saturday
                $dayOfMonth =(int)$day->format('j');    
                $weekNum = ceil($dayOfMonth / 7);           
                if ($dayOfWeek == 6) 
                {           
                    if ($weekNum % 2 == 0)  
                {
              $holiday = $this->getHoliday($day);   //Problem when i call this
               funtion

                  if(empty($holiday)){
                    $no_saturdays += 1 ;                      
                    }
                }   
        }
       .
       .
       . // Further coding

        $workinghours = $workingDays*9 +  $no_saturdays*4;  

        return $workinghours;
        }

        private function getHoliday($day, $countryId){
            $hd = new HoliDay();        
            $hd->Load("dateh = ? and country IS NULL",array($day));
                if($hd->dateh == $day){
                    return $hd;
                }       
            return null;
        }
}
```

If i commented that getholiday() then it get executed but i could not get exact result.

Comment: *But it is not working.* - how?

Comment: that should give you an error as there are two params required you are passing only one abd it returns null hence $holiday will have null value

Comment: Not working means,the html block that im going to dsiplay the values shows empty. Even i tried to place error_log() inside the function just to know whether that function is getting executed.But nothing returns. When i comment that particular line, i get error_log() messages i called.

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI , i tried by passing parameter for countryid, but still same.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the error because the second parameter $countryId is missing.
You should either pass this parameter or setup default value for $countryId like this:

```
private function getHoliday($day, $countryId = null){
        $hd = new HoliDay();        
        $hd->Load("dateh = ? and country IS NULL",array($day));
            if($hd->dateh == $day){
                return $hd;
            }       
        return null;
    }
```